# Is there a way in Telethon to get messages from chats along with the sender name, date and time?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon, telegram-api

I could get messages from chats but I need to add sender name, date and time along with the message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. And everything is explained in the docs, looking through it or simply searching for messages leads you to [`iter_messages`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages).

Below the list of arguments the function takes, you have the instance the method returns. As an example:

```
# From most-recent to oldest
async for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
    print(message.id, message.text)

# From oldest to most-recent
async for message in client.iter_messages(chat, reverse=True):
    print(message.id, message.text)

# Filter by sender
async for message in client.iter_messages(chat, from_user='me'):
    print(message.text)

# Server-side search with fuzzy text
async for message in client.iter_messages(chat, search='hello'):
    print(message.id)

# Filter by message type:
from telethon.tl.types import InputMessagesFilterPhotos
async for message in client.iter_messages(chat, filter=InputMessagesFilterPhotos):
    print(message.photo)

# Getting comments from a post in a channel:
async for message in client.iter_messages(channel, reply_to=123):
    print(message.chat.title, message.text)
```

The returned [Message](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#module-telethon.tl.custom.message) instance has these attributes and methods you can use:

`message.date` - The UTC+0 datetime object indicating when this message was sent. This will always be present except for empty messages.

`message.get_sender()` - Returns [sender](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/user.html) but will make an API call to find the sender unless it’s already cached.

So given all of this you have:

```
async for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
    date = message.date
    sender = await message.get_sender()
    name = sender.first_name
```

Comment: When using `iter_messages`, `message.sender` will always be present. `get_sender` is there for things like message events, where the `sender` might be missing.